# Bootstrap 4: Hidden elements with "d-md-none" in <span> starts linebreak, how to prevent this?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, display

It seems that in Bootstrap 4, the display/hidden classes like "d-md-none" and "d-none d-sm-block" will insert a linebreak and mess up with the look of my site. How is it possible to prevent this?

For instance, the footer is supposed to hide "2014-" on smaller screens, only show ©2019. The below HTML code is used:

```
&copy;<span class="d-none d-sm-block">2014-</span>2019
```

However, it appears that the footer is messed up and the part "©", "2014-" and "2019" are split into three lines. How can I fix this behavior and remove the linebreak effect of Bootstrap 4's display/hidden class? Please help...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `inline` not `block`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

&copy;<span class="d-none d-sm-inline">2014-</span>2019
```

more details: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#notation

Answer (score 1):

hope to help:

The classes make the span elements have display as block, so they render as blocks below each other. Can you use :

```
&copy;<span class="d-none d-sm-inline">2014-</span>2019
```

The inline class instead of block. Or is that of no use for you?